# AWS RDS I/O usage very different from Postgres blocks read

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I created a test Postgres database in AWS RDS.  Created a 100 million row, 2 column table.  Ran select * on that table. Postgres reports "Buffers: shared hit=24722 read=521226" but AWS reports IOPS in the hundreds.  Why this huge discrepancy?  Broadly, I'm trying to figure out how to estimate the number of AWS I/O operations a query might cost.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not have insight into what the kernel/FS get up to.  If PostgreSQL issues a system call to read the data, then it reports that buffer as "read".  If it was actually served out of the kernel's filesystem cache, rather than truly from disk, PostgreSQL has no way of knowing that (although you can make some reasonable statistical guesses if track_io_timing is on), while AWS's IO monitoring tool would know.

If you set shared_buffers to a large fraction of memory, then there would be little room left for a filesystem cache, so most buffers reported as read should truly have been read from disk.  This might not be a good way run the system, but it might provide some clarity to your EXPLAIN plans.  I've also heard rumors that Amazon Aurora reimplemented the storage system so that it uses directIO, or something similar, and so doesn't use the filesystem cache at all.

Comment: I'm not sure this explains it - there was a huge discrepancy in both read I/O and write I/O operations when I ran the code to insert and select the data for the first time.  Can't imagine how write I/O especially could be served out of the cache

Comment: You showed a line from your SELECT.  It doesn't indicate any writing being done, (which makes sense if the table had been vacuumed).  What discrepancy can exist when there is no source of information to disagree.